# Regex - Extract substrings starting with capitalized letter in a list, with french special symbols

Tags: python, regex, french

I have a set of french strings like this one:

```
text = "Français Langues bantoues Presse écrite Gabon Particularité linguistique"
```

I want to extract the substrings starting with capitalized letters into a list, as follows:

```
list = ["Français", "Langues bantoues", "Presse écrite", "Gabon", "Particularité linguistique"]
```

I did try something like that but it does not take the following words, and it stops because of the french symbols.

```
import re
pattern = "([A-Z][a-z]+)"

text = "Français Langues bantoues Presse écrite Gabon Particularité linguistique"

list = re.findall(pattern, text)
list
```

Output
`['Fran', 'Langues', 'Presse', 'Gabon', 'Particularit']`

I did not manage to find the solution on the forum unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is related to specific Unicode character handling, I'd recommend to use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (install using `pip install regex`) and then you can use

```py
import regex
text = "Français Langues bantoues Presse écrite Gabon Particularité linguistique"
matches = regex.split(r'(?!\A)\b(?=\p{Lu})', text)
print( list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), matches)) )
# => ['Français', 'Langues bantoues', 'Presse écrite', 'Gabon', 'Particularité linguistique']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://tio.run/##LY4xCoNAEEV7TzGxcRckTbqASJqksfAANqNZdEDXzewIhpDzBM/hwcxK0n0@vPe/e0o32tO20eBGFmDTmjkSMwtkEF8Z7fpB8lCgbSfjoUYr4x5KNt4bWJeGSQzcsB4tlMhCzdRj6NYFegoQeaHHZOJoQGm6QGa/kaN3PYniROWH6qKrWuVZ5V7F9NZJCvsDHTkmKyp4vKgBnepxqO8I8xkCLkxO6RT@Xq1Bb9sX) and the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/csidl0/1). *Details*:

- `(?!\A)` - position other than start of a string
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=\p{Lu})` - a positive lookahead that requires the next char to be a Unicode uppercase letter.

Note that `map(lambda x: x.strip(), matches)` is used to strip off redundant whitespace from the resulting chunks.

You **can do this with `re`, too**:

```py
import re, sys
text = "Français Langues bantoues Presse écrite Gabon Particularité linguistique"
pLu = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]))
matches = re.split(fr'(?!\A)\b(?={pLu})', text)
print( list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), matches)) )
# => ['Français', 'Langues bantoues', 'Presse écrite', 'Gabon', 'Particularité linguistique']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/CMblWW), but bear in mind that the amount of supported Unicode uppercase letters differs from version to version, and using the PyPi regex module makes it more consistent.

Comment: Your code works like a charm, thanks for your very detailed answer !